# Win logon script to run Fn + F12

Tags: windows-7, script

How do you write a script that will run the Fn + F12 keys on logon of an HP netbook running Win 7 Home 32-bit? The "Fn" key is the function key found on laptops/netbooks. Thank you.

Comment: I know what Fn does, but every manufacturer has a different arrangement for the function keys it's used with.  So what does your F12 key do?

Comment: Fn + F12 disables the touchpad on the netbook.

Comment: Fn keys don't generally output a keycode so the OS never sees them. You need a way to programatically perform the function that the key combination provides. Your question should be "How can I disable the touchpad by default on boot?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AutoHotKey:

- http://www.autohotkey.com/

It has a script generator that would allow you to actually "see" what is being pressed and you get the script for free. It's easy to make the script load on startup.

I never used it on Fn-supported keys, though - try it and see if it does. If nothing else, it's easy to try.

Comment: Thanks, icyrock.com. I'll download their tool and see what can be done. Your help is much appreciated :)